# Which level of privacy was chosen from Facebook's publish permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook's iOS SDK (2.x API) to request for permission to post to the user's wall. The user has a choice for the level of privacy of the posts - public, friends, or private.

[image]

How would I determine which level of privacy the user chose? The completion handler of the permission acquisition does not have any arguments that tell me the level. I would like to know so I don't display levels in my interface that the user won't post to.

```
[[FBSession activeSession]
    requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Which level of privacy was chosen?
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: @WizKid My UI asks the user where they want to post the content (public, friends, or private). It would be considered bad UX for them to get an error when attempting to post to public when they've only allowed a maximum level of friends. It would be better UX to not display the public level at all.

Comment: You can't determine what they chose, this is by design. Your UX probably should not show or control any privacy levels.

Comment: @MingLi It's bad UX if the user doesn't know where you're posting content with `/me/feed`. The user might want to post "*I'm at McDonalds in Chicago on Main street. Anyone want to join me for lunch?*"This kind of info would be most appropriate for friends only. If the app randomly chooses between public / friends / private without user input, bad things could happen. If posted to public, perverts could figure out the location of the user and show up at the same McDonalds. If posted to private, the user will be eating lunch alone.

Comment: In that case you should use the share dialog to post rather than posting to /me/feed directly. It gives the users more control, and also presents a unified Facebook UX (users expect that they're posting to FB).

Comment: I just did a test on allowing a maximum of friends level access, but posting at a public level. The post will succeed. Facebook will automatically decrease the level from public to friends.